# undefined behaviour error but code works fine

Tags: javascript

Output -

super customer for product1

good customer for product2

potential customer for product3

undefined

Question - Why am I getting that undefined at the end?

```
var customer = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    moneySpent: [],
    getTotal: function(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            sum += this.moneySpent[i];
        }
        return sum;
    },
    getLevel: function(){
        var level = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 1000){
                level = "super";
            }else if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 500 && this.moneySpent[i] < 1000){
                level = "good";
            }else{
                level = "potential";
            }
            console.log(level + " customer for " + "product" + (i+1));
        }
    }
};



var customer1 = Object.create(customer);
customer1.firstname = "First1";
customer1.lastname = "Last1";
customer1.moneySpent = [1080.89, 783.23, 68.09];

console.log(customer1.getLevel());
```

Comment: return something in `getLevel` method
`getLevel: () => {
   // your code
  return ;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you console.log() used twice.
It should correct as follows

```js
var customer = {
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    moneySpent: [],
    getTotal: function(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            sum += this.moneySpent[i];
        }
        return sum;
    },
    getLevel: function(){
        var level = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 1000){
                level = "super";
            }else if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 500 && this.moneySpent[i] < 1000){
                level = "good";
            }else{
                level = "potential";
            }
            console.log(level + " customer for " + "product" + (i+1));
        }
    }
    };



    var customer1 = Object.create(customer);
    customer1.firstname = "First1";
    customer1.lastname = "Last1";
    customer1.moneySpent = [1080.89, 783.23, 68.09];

    customer1.getLevel()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function returns `undefined` by default when you don't provide an explicit `return`.

`getLevel` function doesn't return anything so by default `undefined` is returned. If you do something like this, you'll get a returned value.

```
getLevel: function(){
        var level = "";
        ...
        return level //or return true will give you a truthy value
    }
```

Comment: how can i get rid of it? New to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

You are not returning anything from a function thats why your console log will be `undefined`

Either use `return;` and dont use `console.log` OR return a string to see if something is getting called.

```js
var customer = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            moneySpent: [],
            getTotal: function(){
                var sum = 0;
                for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    sum += this.moneySpent[i];
                }
                return sum;
            },
            getLevel: function(){
                var level = "";
                for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 1000){
                        level = "super";
                    }else if(this.moneySpent[i] >= 500 && this.moneySpent[i] < 1000){
                        level = "good";
                    } else {
                        level = "potential";
                    }
                    console.log(level + " customer for " + "product" + (i+1));
                }
               return 'Done';
        
            }
        };
        
        
        
        var customer1 = Object.create(customer);
        customer1.firstname = "First1";
        customer1.lastname = "Last1";
        customer1.moneySpent = [1080.89, 783.23, 68.09];
        
        console.log(customer1.getLevel());
```

Comment: is there a way to return nothing?

Comment: just use `return;`

Comment: Just use return; but if you console log. It will be undefined.